# WebView does not play audio from a radio from my web page on android 9

Tags: java, android, webview

I am trying to make an online radio through a webview the radio itself if it is inserted in my google sites website and the problem is that with this code it reproduces it correctly in android 6.0.1

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
miWebView =findViewById(R.id.weebV);
miWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
miWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);

miWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
{
    miWebView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode( WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW );

}
miWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    miWebView.loadUrl("https://sites.google.com/view/radiocristianos/cristianos-radio");
```

}

but I tried it on android 9 and it doesn't play the audio

this is the manifest
before putting the code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
 {
miWebView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode( WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW );

 }
```

I had the problem that I did not play the audio but after putting that code above it works for me but only on android 6.0.1

but now I try it on android 9 and it doesn't work

this is the radio (https://sites.google.com/view/radiocristianos/cristianos-radio)

I would greatly appreciate your help

Comment: You can use webchromeclient

Comment: I already did it and the error continues